# I don't understand React Native Typeerror - Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building an agenda app, which I am implementing a login with connect with authentication firebase, which I am using redux which I do the Types - Actions - Reducers. I am implementing it for 4 days and it throws me this error

> ```
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or
> a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Welcome`.
>
> This error is located at:
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by Welcome)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by Welcome)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by KeyboardAvoidingView)
>      in KeyboardAvoidingView (created by Welcome)
>      in Welcome (created by SceneView)
>      in StaticContainer
>      in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
>      in SceneView (created by SceneView)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by DebugContainer)
>      in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
>      in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by SceneView)
>      in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
>      in Animated Component
>      in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
>      in Suspend (created by Freeze)
>      in Suspense (created by Freeze)
>      in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
>      in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
>      in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
>      in Screen (created by SceneView)
>      in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
>      in Suspend (created by Freeze)
>      in Suspense (created by Freeze)
>      in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
>      in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
>      in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
>      in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
>      in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
>      in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
>      in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
>      in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
>      in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
>      in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
>      in NavigationContent
>      in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
>      in NativeStackNavigator (created by AuthNavigator)
>      in AuthNavigator (created by AppNavigator)
>      in EnsureSingleNavigator
>      in BaseNavigationContainer
>      in ThemeProvider
>      in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigator)
>      in AppNavigator (created by index)
>      in Provider (created by index)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by index)
>      in index (created by withDevTools(index))
>      in withDevTools(index)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by AppContainer)
>      in RCTView (created by View)
>      in View (created by AppContainer)
>      in AppContainer
>      in main(RootComponent)
> ```

The login system is with firebase authentication, I think everything is implemented fine but that error appears.

The `Type` like this

```js
export const userTypes = {
  SIGN_UP: 'SIGN_UP',
  SIGN_IN: 'SIGN_IN',
}
```

The reducer like this

```js
import { userTypes } from '../types';

const { SIGN_UP, SIGN_IN}  = userTypes;

const initialState = {
  token: null,
  userId: null,
};

export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_UP:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.token,
        userId: action.userId,
      };
    case SIGN_IN:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.token,
        userId: action.userId,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userReducer;
```

the action like this

```js
import { URL_AUTH_SIGN_IN, URL_AUTH_SIGN_UP } from '../../constants/firebase';
import { userTypes } from '../types';

const { SIGN_UP, SIGN_IN } = userTypes;

export const signUp = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL_AUTH_SIGN_UP, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      dispatch({
        type: SIGN_UP,
        token: data.idToken,
        userId: data.localId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
};

export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL_AUTH_SIGN_IN, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      dispatch({
        type: SIGN_IN,
        token: data.idToken,
        userId: data.localId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
};
```

and the screen

```
/* eslint-disable no-case-declarations */
import { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import { View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { styles } from './styles';
import { Input } from '../../components';
import Colors  from '../../constants/color';
import { signIn, signUp } from '../../store/actions';
import { UPDATED_FORM, onInputChange } from '../../utils/forms';

const initialState = {
  email: { value: '', error: '', touched: false, hasError: true },
  password: { value: '', error: '', touched: false, hasError: true },
  isFormValid: false,
};

const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATED_FORM:
      const { name, value, hasError, error, touched, isFormValid } = action.data;
      return {
        ...state,
        [name]: {
          ...state[name],
          value,
          hasError,
          error,
          touched,
        },
        isFormValid,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
const Welcome = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(formReducer, initialState);
  const title = isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register';
  const message = isLogin ? "Don't have an account?" : 'Already have an account?';
  const messageButton = isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register';

  const onHandlerSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(
      isLogin
        ? signIn(formState.email.value, formState.password.value)
        : signUp(formState.email.value, formState.password.value)
    );
  };

  const onHandlerInputChange = (value, type) => {
    onInputChange(type, value, dispatchFormState, formState);
  };
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.keybordContainer}
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'height' : 'padding'}
      enabled>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
          <Input
            placeholder="enter your email"
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(text) => onHandlerInputChange(text, 'email')}
            value={formState.email.value}
            hasError={formState.email.hasError}
            error={formState.email.error}
            touched={formState.email.touched}
            label="Email"
            labelStyle={styles.label}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="enter your password"
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray}
            secureTextEntry
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(text) => onHandlerInputChange(text, 'password')}
            value={formState.password.value}
            hasError={formState.password.hasError}
            error={formState.password.error}
            touched={formState.password.touched}
            label="Password"
            labelStyle={styles.label}
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button title={messageButton} color={Colors.primary} onPress={onHandlerSubmit} />
            <View style={styles.prompt}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.promptButton} onPress={() => setIsLogin(!isLogin)}>
                <Text style={styles.promptMessage}>{message}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

and the style file

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../../constants/color';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  keybordContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    width: '80%',
    maxWidth: 400,
    padding: 15,
    margin: 15,
    borderColor: Colors.primary,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: 5,
    minHeight: 330,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  prompt: {
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  promptButton: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: Colors.secondary,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.primary,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  promptMessage: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular',
    color: Colors.white,
  },
});
```

I also place the packages that I use in the app

```json
{
  "name": "agendamounkey",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "expo": "^47.0.12",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "yet": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I need to know why it gives this error and how to fix it, and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Add the code where you imported **welcome** component

Comment: When the error occurs?

Comment: I look like you are importing wrong module where Welcome component is used, i think in app.js

Comment: If possible provide a project repo link to figure out error or check the exact position of error.

Comment: To your comments thank you very much, responding to these:
1.- the welcome is inside navigation and this is attached to index inside the src folder.

Comment: 2.-this happens when the app starts, but it tends to load the scene for a few seconds (welcome)
3.-In app.js there is only this code that redirects to src/index.js
import App from "./src/index";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

registerRootComponent(App);import App from "./src/index";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

registerRootComponent(App);

4.- the repo on Github is this https://github.com/mounkey/AgendaMounkey

Comment: I already solved it, a component was missing, link it